# Python calculate ageing of outlook mail items

Tags: python, email

I am trying to develop an application in wxPython in which I will fetch all e-mails into a listctrl and sort them based on their remaining SLA (3 days) for further action. For this I will calculate the ageing of the items in the mailbox by deducting the receivedTime from current time. Below is my complete code:-

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import win32com.client
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, myTitle):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent, title = myTitle, size = (1300,600))
    #set the background color
    self.index = 0
    self.SetBackgroundColour((230, 230, 250))

    #create fonts
    FrameLabels_Font = wx.Font(10, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD, True, u'Bookman Old Style')
    listItems_Font = wx.Font(8, wx.DECORATIVE, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL, True, u'Bookman Old Style')

    #set the frame
    self.frame_Controls = wx.StaticBox(self, label="Controls:-", pos=(10, 275), size=(300, 250), style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
    self.frame_Controls.SetBackgroundColour((230, 230, 250))
    self.frame_Controls.SetFont(FrameLabels_Font)
    self.frame_Summary = wx.StaticBox(self, label="Stats:-", pos=(10, 10), size=(300, 250), style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
    self.frame_Summary.SetBackgroundColour((230, 230, 250))
    self.frame_Summary.SetFont(FrameLabels_Font)
    self.frame_Queue = wx.StaticBox(self, label="Work Items:-", pos=(320, 10), size=(950, 515), style=wx.RAISED_BORDER)
    self.frame_Queue.SetBackgroundColour((230, 230, 250))
    self.frame_Queue.SetFont(FrameLabels_Font)

    #controls for queue frame
    LblRegion = wx.StaticText(self.frame_Queue, -1, 'Region:-', (20, 25), (150, 25))
    LblMailbox = wx.StaticText(self.frame_Queue, -1, 'Mailbox:-', (190, 25), (150, 25))
    LblSortBy = wx.StaticText(self.frame_Queue, -1, 'Sort By:-', (360, 25), (150, 25))
    LblSortOrder = wx.StaticText(self.frame_Queue, -1, 'Sort Order:-', (530, 25), (150, 25))

    rdoUnallocated = myRadioButton(self.frame_Queue, 'UnAllocated', (700,25), (110,25))
    rdoAllocated = myRadioButton(self.frame_Queue, 'Allocated', (820, 25), (110, 25))

    rgnCombo = myComboBox(self.frame_Queue,(20,60),(150,25))
    rgnCombo = myComboBox(self.frame_Queue, (190, 60), (150, 25))
    rgnCombo = myComboBox(self.frame_Queue, (360, 60), (150, 25))
    rgnCombo = myComboBox(self.frame_Queue, (530, 60), (150, 25))

    self.subList = myListCtrl(self.frame_Queue,(20,95),(910,390))
    self.subList.InsertColumn(0, 'Rush')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(1, 'Subject')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(2, 'Recevd DtTm')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(3, 'Allocated To')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(4, 'Allo. ID')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(5, 'Unique Key')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(6, 'Rem. SLA')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(7, 'Ageing')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(8, 'Duplicate')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(9, 'Actionable')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(10, 'Status')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(11, 'Start DtTm')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(12, 'Query DtTm')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(13, 'Hold DtTm')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(14, 'Continue DtTm')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(15, 'Final Status')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(16, 'Final Status DtTm')
    self.subList.InsertColumn(17, 'Final Status Date')

    #update the listctrl
    getConn = OutlookConnection()
    messages = getConn.fetchUnallocated()
    for msg in messages:
        self.subList.InsertStringItem(self.index, '')
        self.subList.SetItemFont(self.index, listItems_Font)
        self.subList.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, msg.subject)
        self.subList.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, str(msg.receivedtime))
        if msg.Importance == 2:
            self.subList.SetStringItem(self.index, 0, 'Y')
            self.subList.SetItemBackgroundColour(self.index, (255,0,0))
        #tm = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") - msg.receivedtime
        #tm = datetime.now() - msg.receivedtime
        tm = time.mktime(datetime.now().timetuple()) - msg.receivedtime
        #tm = datetime.now() - datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(msg.receivedtime))
        #self.subList.SetStringItem(self.index, 7, str(datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")))
        self.subList.SetStringItem(self.index, 7, str(tm))

    #add the menu here
    self.AddMenu()

    #display the frame
    self.Centre()
    self.Show()

#create the AddMenu def
def AddMenu(self):
    menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
    #file menu
    File_btn = wx.Menu()
    #sub menu items of file menu
    #Logout
    Logout_btn = File_btn.Append(wx.ID_EXIT,'&Logout', 'Close the application')
    #now put the File_btn to the menuBar
    menuBar.Append(File_btn, '&File')
    #set the menu bar in the application main frame
    self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
    #now bind the code which will run upon clicking the Logout button
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Quit, Logout_btn)

#def the self.Quit process
def Quit(self,x):
    self.Close()

#class for querying database
class dbQuery():
#method for getting the list of regions
    def RegionsList(self):
        myDb = 'H:\\Python\\wxPython\\Programs\\References.accdb'
        DRV = '{Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}'
        PWD = 'pw'
    # connect to db
        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=%s' % (myDb))
        cur = conn.cursor()
    # run a query and get the results
        SQL = 'SELECT * FROM Regions'
        return cur.execute(SQL, self.Tname).fetchall()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()


class myRadioButton(wx.RadioButton):
    def __init__(self, parent, mylabel, vPosition, vSize):
        super(myRadioButton, self).__init__(parent, -1, label = mylabel, pos = vPosition, size = vSize)

class myComboBox(wx.ComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent, lstposition, lstsize):
        super(myComboBox, self).__init__(parent, -1, value="", pos=lstposition, size=lstsize)
    #this method will be used to add items from a list to the instance of the mycombobox
    def addItem(self, Lst=[]):
        for itm in Lst:
            self.Append(itm)

class myListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl):
    def __init__(self,parent, vPosition, vSize):
        super(myListCtrl, self).__init__(parent, -1, pos = vPosition, size = vSize, style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)


class OutlookConnection():
    def fetchUnallocated(self):
        outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
        inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)  # "6" refers to the index of a folder - in this case inbox,
        return inbox.Items


app = wx.App()
FIR_Frame = MainFrame(None, 'F.I.R - TL Interface')
app.MainLoop()
```

The challenge I am facing is in the line where I am trying to calculate the ageing of the mail item:-

```
tm = datetime.now() - msg.receivedtime
self.subList.SetStringItem(self.index, 7, str(tm))
```

I am getting error :-
*tm = datetime.now() - msg.receivedtime
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'time'*

I have tried more formats/ways... you can see them in the above code resulting in similar errors

Can someone please help me with calculating the ageing in 'HH:MM:SS' format. Also the hours should populate in greater than 24 wherever required (i.e if ageing is more than 24 hours).

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,
Premanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, here is one way.
Check what the structure of `msg.receivedtime` is and then convert it into seconds to be able to manipulate it. I am assuming the following structure of `msg.receivedtime` "2016-08-30 10:30:15"
Use `time.time()` rather than `datetime.now()` to get `now`

```
>>> tm = int(time.time())
>>> tm
1472550462
>>> msg_receivedtime = "2016-08-30 10:30:15"
>>> msg_tuple = time.strptime(msg_receivedtime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> msg_stamp = int(time.mktime(msg_tuple))
>>> msg_stamp
1472545815
>>> print tm - msg_stamp
4647
```

Note: I have reduced the time stamps to integer seconds in both cases
Edit:
to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss

```
>>> x = 4647
>>> m,s =divmod(x,60)
>>> h,m =divmod(m,60)
>>> print h,m,s
1 17 27
```

Edit: Concerning comment about date stamps more than 48 hours old

You must be doing something wrong!
Here is the code from above, using a value of time.time() as of Monday 5th September 2016.

```
>>> import time
>>> tm = int(time.time())
>>> tm
1473064274
>>> msg_receivedtime = "2016-08-30 10:30:15"
>>> msg_tuple = time.strptime(msg_receivedtime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> msg_stamp = int(time.mktime(msg_tuple))
>>> msg_stamp
1472545815
>>> x = tm - msg_stamp
>>> x
518459
>>> m,s =divmod(x,60)
>>> h,m =divmod(m,60)
>>> print h,m,s
144 0 59
```

Note that 144 hours is 6 days
Which is what you required:

> Can someone please help me with calculating the ageing in 'HH:MM:SS' format. Also the hours should populate in greater than 24 wherever required (i.e if ageing is more than 24 hours).

Comment: this has helped me to get the time difference in seconds. Can you also now suggest how do I convert these seconds back into 'hh:mm' format to display in my app

Comment: so basically I am trying to show the ageing of the mail item in 'hh:mm' format since when it has dropped in the mailbox. Thank you again for your help... I have been waiting for a response on this for last 2 days and finally you came with a solution

Comment: Hi Rolf, am very sorry I noticed this lately that the ageing of mailitems in my app is not calculating correctly. The reason I could understand is because we are using time to calculate the ageing, instead we must use the datetime to calculate it... i.e for mail item received 3 days back instead of calculating ageing of more than 48 hours it is calculating only 14 hours