# wxPython how to get row ID of list item that is double clicked

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

I am working on a wxPython app in which I have used a wx.ListCtrl with 12 columns. The control gets populated with some values upon clicking a button... let's say Name, Age, Class, House... etc.

Now I want to create a double click event which upon double cliking a list item should pop-up a msgbox with the Name value, however I am unable to get the row number or ID of the row item that is being double clicked...

here is my Code:-

```
self.subList.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_ACTIVATED, self.DblClickOptions)

def DblClickOptions(self, extra):
    itm = self.subList.GetItem(itemId='???', col=1)
    itm_text = itm.GetText()
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, itm_text, "title", 1)
```

in the code above I need to get the row number of the list item that is double clicked in place of '???'

Please someone help me with this.

Regards,
Premanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Events/wx.ListEvent.html#methods-summary

(typically the variable you named `extra` is named `event` or `evt` ...)

`extra.GetIndex()` would be the row id

`extra.GetText()` would be the row text

etc

Comment: this is Awesome :). Thank you Joran for your help. I am new to Python and this is my first attempt to develop something.

Comment: I just jumped into coding and did not go through much of any tutorial... so did not knew the proper way of coding... named extra instead of event... actually put it there when I got a error saying the method needs to 1 argument and provided 1 even when I did not call it with any argument, so to solve it just put one extra argument in the method itself.

Comment: also would you be kind enough to answer one more post of mine in this same forum.... I will forward that to you on your ID. Please help if you can on this as well.... thank you so much in advance

Comment: here is the link to my other question:-

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39189689/python-calculate-ageing-of-outlook-mail-items)